# Scipy whitening in advance of kmeans clustering

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I'm trying to cluster some data using `kmeans` from `sklearn.cluster`. But I want to whiten my data first. I have a Pandas df with the following three columns (there are a couple hundred rows):

```
1) zipcode
2) highclust
3) callclust
```

I want to whiten (using `scipy.cluster.vq.whiten`). From what I've researched so far, the df columns have to converted to a matrix before whitening. So I did:

`features = df.as_matrix(columns = ['highclust', 'callclust'])`

Then I used `whiten(features)`.

That worked fine, but now I want to get those values back onto the original df.

The problem is that I've got no values to merge it back with. If I bring `zipcode` into `features` when I create it, the zipcode gets whitened along with `highclust` and `callclust`, rendering it useless.

Comment: You _could_ just create a new df and store the results in there, rather than force them back into the old frame?

Comment: I've no idea how spicy whiten works, but perhaps you could do something like `df['highclust'] = whitened[:, 0]`? Not a pretty solution, but it may suffice for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to first save the zipcodes, whiten, and then reapply zipcodes.

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import whiten
import pandas as pd

zips = df.zipcode
df = pd.DataFrame(whiten(df), columns=df.columns)
df['zipcode'] = zips
```

You can also just do the calcs yourself instead of using scipy using a lambda function.

```
np.random.seed(0)

whiten_cols = ['highclust', 'callclust']
df = pd.DataFrame({'zipcode': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                   'highclust': np.random.randn(5), 
                   'callclust': np.random.randn(5)})[['zipcode'] + whitencols]

>>> df
   zipcode  highclust  callclust
0        1   1.764052  -0.977278
1        2   0.400157   0.950088
2        3   0.978738  -0.151357
3        4   2.240893  -0.103219
4        5   1.867558   0.410599    

>>> df.std() 
zipcode      1.581139
highclust    0.745445
callclust    0.717038
dtype: float64    

# Whiten data.
df.loc[:, whiten_cols] = df[whiten_cols].apply(lambda col: col / col.std())

>>> df
   zipcode  highclust  callclust
0        1   2.366442  -1.362937
1        2   0.536803   1.325018
2        3   1.312958  -0.211087
3        4   3.006115  -0.143952
4        5   2.505293   0.572631

>>> df.std()
zipcode      1.581139
highclust    1.000000
callclust    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

Pandas normalizes the standard deviation by N-1 by default.  This won't be an issue on a large dataset, but you can match the scipy results with:

```
df.loc[:, whiten_cols] = df[whiten_cols].apply(lambda col: col / col.std(ddof=0))

>>> df
   zipcode  highclust  callclust
0        1   2.645763  -1.523810
1        2   0.600164   1.481415
2        3   1.467932  -0.236002
3        4   3.360938  -0.160943
4        5   2.801003   0.640221
```

If you prefer to use scipy directly:

```
# After resetting the seed and reinitializing the dataframe.
df.loc[:, whiten_cols] = whiten(df[whiten_cols].values)

>>> df
   zipcode  highclust  callclust
0        1   2.645763  -1.523810
1        2   0.600164   1.481415
2        3   1.467932  -0.236002
3        4   3.360938  -0.160943
4        5   2.801003   0.640221

>>> df.std()
zipcode      1.581139
highclust    1.118034
callclust    1.118034
dtype: float64
```

> [scipy.cluster.vq.whiten](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.whiten.html)
>
> scipy.cluster.vq.whiten(obs, check_finite=True)[source]
>   Normalize a group of observations on a per feature basis.
>
> Before running k-means, it is beneficial to rescale each feature dimension of 
>    the observation set with whitening. Each feature is divided by its standard 
>   deviation across all observations to give it unit variance.

This is the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/cluster/vq.py#L96) for `whiten`:

```
obs = _asarray_validated(obs, check_finite=check_finite)
std_dev = std(obs, axis=0)
zero_std_mask = std_dev == 0
if zero_std_mask.any():
    std_dev[zero_std_mask] = 1.0
    warnings.warn("Some columns have standard deviation zero. "
                  "The values of these columns will not change.",
                  RuntimeWarning)
return obs / std_dev
```